# Flurry Doesn´t show data in Real Time Analytics window and doesn't capture crash errors

Tags: flurry

I'm testing my integration of a Flurry application and over the last two days it;

1. Doesn't show the data on Flurry application web in pages with Real Time.
2. Nor does it capture errors on window crash. I get everything at 0.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivd47rwcpdhruqw/Flurry%20ok.jpg?dl=0) is my data for two days ago:

The output is also shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yi0fmgkb32haoep/Flurry%20error.png?dl=0).

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score -1):

same problem, maybe caused by "Restricted Feature Set", I did not notice any "disable" button there as mention in their explain page.
sent ticket two weeks ago, support reply that we need to prove apps "no longer showing directed at children", still waiting for next instruction to restore status.

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/restrictedset/